# Best practice to store/check read state

Tags: mongodb

Lets imagine we have a public (available to anyone) list of some items, like articles, in quantity of N. By default all new articles are unread. Articles are stored in mongodb in collection named **articles**, each article having unique id.

Then we have P number of users. Each user can read individual article, and by doing this the particular article must be marked as read for particular user. So there must be some way to store that particular user have read particular article. This, of course, means that for some users this article can be read, and for some unread.

So before showing to user the article list, we need to crosscheck articles for read/unread state, and display read ones accordingly, lets say unbold them.

Now, there are two ways I see to handle read/unread state.

**First** is to make a separate collection, **readstate**, and store there pairs of {article_id, user_id}. Assuming that by default all articles are unread, we crosscheck article list with this collection, and if for particular article crosscheck succeeds (meaning that there is a pair of user_id and article_id in the *readstate* collection, and so the article is read), we add **read:true** to the output for this article.

**Second** approach is to add to each article entry an array of user_id values that are read this article. Before output we check user_id with values in that array for each entry, and if there is a match, we add **read:true** to the output for this article.

In simple conditions, the second approach will work faster (i believe) and will take less cpu/ram resources to work, but what if we'll have like million of articles, million of users and limited resources? The second approach based on finding certain user_id in the array, which heavily relies on available RAM, right? And even maybe it will fail if we have insufficient RAM? Also, if this array is already big enough, how fast will be pushing/popping operations on this array?

The benefint of first approach is that crossmatching can be prety fast if properly index entries in **readstate** collection, and, possibly will be less resource-consuming, but still it will be slower, than second variant.

This is all my suggestions, and I hope I explained them quite understandable.

What methods can you recommend to handle this task and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, three ways:

- Keep a separate collection of which users have read which articles;
- Keep, embedded in each article, a list of which users have read it;
- **Keep, embedded in each user, a list of articles they have read.**

Which is fastest depends on what you usually want to know: if, for a given article, you want to know which users have read it, keeping a list of users on the article is a very fast way to answer that question, and keeping a list of articles with the user is not.  The use case you mention specifically is the converse: for a given user, if you want to know which articles they have read, keeping a list of articles with the user will be much faster than keeping a list of users with the article.

A few other things to consider:

- With embedding in either direction, every time a user reads an article, one of those two documents is updated by adding a key to it, which means the documents in that collection monotonically increase in size, which is how fragmentation happens.  If you keep read events separately, most likely inserts to the readstate collection (including its indexes) will vastly outnumber updates to either articles or users, and there will be little if any fragmentation.
- If you're paginating headlines for a user, keeping read events separately allows you to fetch a range of them without loading either every user who has ever read an article, or every article a user has ever read.
- Every time you read the words "documents increase monotonically in size" your next thought should be, "... until they reach 16MB, whereupon the next attempt to add something to them will fail."

Comment: hmm.. yes, somehow I didn't thing about third variant.. and a 16 mb limit. Thank you for broadwide answer, Ben.